# SAS allign column by comma and decimal

Tags: sas

[image]

I have a problem with aligning column with 'min, max' and 'q1, q3'. I have predetermined number format and I cannot change it. Five digit number and four digit number cause an error.  I would like to have only one space AFTER comma. In column B problem is.
Can I somehow break down column by comma and glue it again?
I have no idea.

I work in SAS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried?  How did you produce the table you posted the photograph of?

Comment: Please do not post images as data, please post them as text. To work with your data we'd have to type it out and that reduces the number of people willing to answer your question and makes it harder to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `compbl` to remove double spaces in strings:

> The COMPBL function removes multiple blanks in a character string by
> translating each occurrence of two or more consecutive blanks into a
> single blank.

[Documentation](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/p1si0i16bcqti7n1jxxxe1hstunq.htm)

`B = compbl(B);`

You can leave your structure as-is. The code below will remove double spaces from all character variables.

```
data want;
    set have;
    array charvars[*] _CHARACTER_;
    
    do i = 1 to dim(charvars);
        charvars[i] = compbl(charvars[i]);
    end;
    
    drop i;
run;
```